# Arreglo de objetos ksoap

Tags: android, array, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio, estoy consumiendo un webservices en asmx.

El detalle es que tengo en mi websevices un método que se llama `menú`, el cual me trae en un xml el menu, el cual lo quiero mostrar un `ListView`, el detalle es que cuando ejecuto la app. Si me hace la conexión, si veo que me trae el xml, pero cuando lo trato de mostrar en el `listview` no me muestra nada... revisando foros vi que tenia que poner un `for` para que fuera recorriendo uno en uno, pero no lo hace, ah y estoy usando la `class AsyncStack`.

Les dejo el código donde mando a llamar el webservices y el codigo de mi `activity` donde implemento el `listview`.

**webservices:**

```
package com.example.onc_lap.proyecto;

/**
 * Created by ONC-LAP on 19/04/2016.
 */

        import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
        import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
        import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

        import java.util.List;

public class webService {
    //Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://ONControl_MobileWS/";
    //Webservice URL - WSDL File location
    private static String URL = "http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ONControl_MobileWS.asmx";//Make sure you changed IP address
    //SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "Login";
    private static List arraylist;

    public static boolean Login(String usuario,String contrasena, String conexion) {
            boolean loginStatus = false;
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        // Property which holds input parameters
        PropertyInfo unamePI = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo passPI = new PropertyInfo();
        // Set Username
        unamePI.setName("Usuario");
        // Set Value
        unamePI.setValue(usuario);
        // Set dataType
        unamePI.setType(String.class);
        // Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(unamePI);
        //Set Password
        passPI.setName("Contrasena");
        //Set dataType
        passPI.setValue(contrasena);
        //Set dataType
        passPI.setType(String.class);
        //Add the property to request object
        request.addProperty(passPI);
        // Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/Login", envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
            loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            MainActivity.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Return booleam to calling object
        return loginStatus;
    }

    public static void Menu() {
        String MenuResult = "";
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","Menu");
        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/Menu", envelope);
            // Get the response
            SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            SoapObject obj2 =(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(0);


            for (int i = 0; i< obj2.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                int opci = Integer.parseInt(obj2.getProperty(0).toString());

                // String id1=obj2.getProperty(0).toString();

                if(opci != 0)
                {
                    arraylist.add(""+ opci);

                }
                /* tv3.setText(id3);*/
            }
           // SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
          //  MenuResult = response.toString();
//            String ASDF ="333";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
package com.example.onc_lap.proyecto;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ONC-LAP on 19/04/2016.
 */
public class menu extends Activity {

    Button btnmenu;
    String ResultMenu;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView listmenu;
    ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        listmenu=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listmenu);

        btnmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmenu);
        btnmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AsyncCallWSMenu task = new AsyncCallWSMenu();
                //Call execute
                task.execute();

            }
        });
        {

        }

    }

    private class AsyncCallWSMenu extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)         {
            webService.Menu();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        //Make Progress Bar visible
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog=new ProgressDialog(menu.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params) {
        }

        @Override
        //Once WebService returns response
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {

            if(arraylist.size()!=0){
                dialog.dismiss();
                arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( menu.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, arraylist );
                listmenu.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
            }else{
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No tienes algún mensaje de error en el LogCat?

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente asegura que en tu método `Menu()` que se ejecuta dentro de `doInBackground()`, este agregando los datos dentro del arrayList:

```
arraylist.add(""+ opci);
```

Ya que si no tiene datos este `ArrayList`, simplemente no contendra datos el Adapter y no se mostraran en tu listado:

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {    
        if(arraylist.size()!=0){
            dialog.dismiss();
            arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( menu.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, arraylist);
            listmenu.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
        }else{
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

- Te comento dos sugerencias:

1) Puedes realizar un cast de un entero con String.valueOf():

```
 arraylist.add(String.valueOf(opci));
```

en lugar de usar:

```
 arraylist.add(""+ opci);
```

2) Para validar si un ArrayList contiene datos usa el método [isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#isEmpty()):

```
if(arraylist.isEmpty()){
...
...
```

Comment: mira use este codigo String ss=androidHttpTransport.responseDump; y me muestra mi xml.. pero veo que dicen que lo tengo que imprimir, como lo muestro en mi listview?

Comment: Si tienes como respuesta un xml debes crear entonces un parser y eso es otro tema, si creas el parser puedes obtener los elementos que usarias para agregar a tu arraylist: arraylist.add( ... );

Comment: a ver entonces tu que me recomiendas... a mi me estan enviando por medio de webservices un menu en formato xml... el cual pues yo lo debo de mostrar en listview u otro elemento no ceseriamente tiene que ser en un listview, cual es tu recomendacion para leer, obtener y mostrar los datos del xml?